# Как правильно развернуть .NET DLL для Office

Tags: .net, dll, vba, com, office

Допустим, где-то на сервере лежит БД MS Access, на этом сервере зарегистрирована .NET DLL, которая используется в модулях MS Access.

База доступна по шаре для других пользователей и нужно, что бы у них все модули работали=>нужно все развернуть на машинах пользователей.

Соответственно меня интересуют следующие вопросы:

1. Нужно ли давайть строгое имя и регистрировать в GAC или можно обойтись без GAC?
2. Если на сервере в модуле выбрана x64 библиотека, а на машинах пользователей нужно развернуть х86 DLL, то понадобится на машинах пользователя править Reference в модуле VBA или все само разрулится?
3. После регистрации DLL всегда будет отображаться в списке VBA Reference(Например, пользователь хочет написать модуль с использование данной DLL) или нужно руками указывать на нее путь?